# MariaDB, Django, and 127.0.0.1

Tags: mysql, django, mariadb

I was using MySQL with Django, with everything working fine.

This is my Django database config—

```
DATABASES['default'] = {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'USER': 'putty',
    'PASSWORD': 'putty',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'NAME': 'putty',
}
```

And here's what I ran in MySQL to create databases and users—

```
CREATE DATABASE putty CHARACTER SET = 'utf8';
CREATE USER 'putty'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'putty';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON putty.* TO 'putty'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

However, when I installed MariaDB, wiped my MySQL data directory, and tried the above, I can no longer connect to my database.

Django says—

```
OperationalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'putty'")
```

If I change my Django database config as such—

```
    'HOST': 'localhost',
```

It works fine (this, however, is not feasible since it doesn't work our production MySQL).

**How can I force MariaDB to work with a host of 127.0.0.1?**

I tried deleting the user and re-creating it with a host of 127.0.0.1, but MariaDB doesn't let me.

## Update

Logging in at as `putty@127.0.0.1`—

```
mysql -u putty -h 127.0.0.1 -p
SHOW DATABASES;
```

I can only see one database (`information_schema`).

However, as `putty@localhost` I can see them all. Weird.

## Update

Even logging in as `root@127.0.0.1`, I can't create a database.

When I set `--protocol=TCP` I get the same; however with `--protocol=SOCKET` things work fine.

Answer (score 1):

`localhost` is special in the MariaDB/MySQL context.  It selects the UNIX domain socket connection.  127.0.0.1 uses the TCP/IP connection.  They are completely different.  Your permissions need to explicitly state that, so in the above, in addition to `'putty'@'localhost'` you need to include `'putty'@'127.0.0.1'`. Note also that they are different users, and can have different permissions and different passwords - and they refer to different connection methods.

In addition you need to ensure that MariaDB is listening on 127.0.0.1.  This is often the default, however older migrated configs may still have *skip-networking* set in **my.cnf**. You will need to comment that out if it is set.  Newer configuration will be bound to the local loopback:

`bind-address = 127.0.0.1`

This should be enough to make sure it accepts a user (with the correct permissions) via 127.0.0.1